# Manipulate depth map of android camera cause the app crash

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-ndk, android-camera2

Trying to access the depth map generated by TOF camera by camera2 api of android, but the app always crash when I copy the depth map.

- Android os : 10
- Android api : 28
- arch : armv8a
- Qt version : Felgo 3.6.0
- Develop on : windows 10 64 bits
- ndk : r18b
- phone : mate30

Error messages : **F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x741c259980 in tid 31512 (ImageReader-480), pid 31412 (P.Androidndkcam)**

Find the back camera support depth16

```
std::tuple<std::string, bool> get_camera_depth_id(ACameraManager *cam_manager, int camera_facing)
{
    auto camera_ids = get_camera_id_list(cam_manager);
    if(camera_ids){
        qInfo()<<__func__<<": found camera count "<<camera_ids->numCameras;
        for(int i = 0; i < camera_ids->numCameras; ++i){
            const char *id = camera_ids->cameraIds[i];
            camera_status_t ret = ACAMERA_OK;
            auto chars = get_camera_characteristics(cam_manager, id, &ret);
            if(ret != ACAMERA_OK){
                qInfo()<<__func__<<": cannot obtain characteristics of camera id = "<<id;
                continue;
            }
            auto const entry = get_camera_capabilities(chars.get(), &ret);
            if(ret != ACAMERA_OK){
                qInfo()<<__func__<<": cannot obtain capabilities of camera id = "<<id;
                continue;
            }

            ACameraMetadata_const_entry lens_info;
            ACameraMetadata_getConstEntry(chars.get(), ACAMERA_LENS_FACING, &lens_info);
            auto const facing = static_cast<acamera_metadata_enum_android_lens_facing_t>(lens_info.data.u8[i]);
            bool is_right_face = facing == camera_facing;
            bool support_bc = false, support_depth = false;
            for(uint32_t i = 0; i < entry.count; i++) {
                if(entry.data.u8[i] == ACAMERA_REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_BACKWARD_COMPATIBLE){
                    support_bc = true;
                }
                if(entry.data.u8[i] == ACAMERA_REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_DEPTH_OUTPUT){
                    support_depth = true;
                }
            }
            qInfo()<<__func__<<" support bc = "<<support_bc<<", support depth = "<<support_depth
                  <<", is right face = "<<is_right_face;
            if(is_right_face && support_depth){
                qInfo()<<__func__<<": obtain depth camera id = "<<id;
                return {id, support_bc};
            }
        }
    }else{
        qInfo()<<__func__<<": cannot get depth cam";
    }

    return {};
}
```

open camera

```
    void initCam()
    {
        qDebug()<<__func__<<": init camera manager";
        cameraManager = ACameraManager_create();

        qDebug()<<__func__<<": get back facing camera id";
        auto [id, support_bc] = get_camera_depth_id(cameraManager, ACAMERA_LENS_FACING_BACK);
        //auto const id = get_camera_id(cameraManager, ACAMERA_LENS_FACING_BACK);
        qInfo()<<__func__<<": back camera id = "<<id.c_str();
        if(!id.empty()){
            auto const cam_status =
                    ACameraManager_openCamera(cameraManager, id.c_str(), &cameraDeviceCallbacks, &cameraDevice);
            qInfo()<<__func__<<" cam status = "<<cam_status;
            qDebug()<<__func__<<": open camera";

            android_cam_info cam_info(*cameraManager, id.c_str());
            qInfo()<<__func__<<" print depth stream configuration info";
            //print the format, width, height, is input information
            cam_info.stream_config(ACAMERA_DEPTH_AVAILABLE_DEPTH_STREAM_CONFIGURATIONS).print();
            //obtain minimum widh and height for the depth map
            std::tie(width_, height_) =
                    cam_info.stream_config(ACAMERA_DEPTH_AVAILABLE_DEPTH_STREAM_CONFIGURATIONS).get_minimum_dimension();

            imageReader = createJpegReader();
            if(imageReader){
                imageWindow = createSurface(imageReader);
                ANativeWindow_acquire(imageWindow);
                ACameraDevice_createCaptureRequest(cameraDevice, TEMPLATE_PREVIEW, &request);
                ACameraOutputTarget_create(imageWindow, &imageTarget);
                ACaptureRequest_addTarget(request, imageTarget);
                ACaptureSessionOutput_create(imageWindow, &imageOutput);
                ACaptureSessionOutputContainer_create(&outputs);
                ACaptureSessionOutputContainer_add(outputs, imageOutput);

                ACameraDevice_createCaptureSession(cameraDevice, outputs, &sessionStateCallbacks, &textureSession);
                // Start capturing continuously
                ACameraCaptureSession_setRepeatingRequest(textureSession, &captureCallbacks, 1, &request, nullptr);
            }
        }
    }
```

The way I create the imageReader

```
    AImageReader* createJpegReader()
    {
        AImageReader* reader = nullptr;
        media_status_t status = AImageReader_new(width_, height_, AIMAGE_FORMAT_DEPTH16, 1, &reader);

        if(status != AMEDIA_OK){
            qInfo()<<__func__<<": cannot create AImageReader, error code is = "<<status;
            return nullptr;
        }

        AImageReader_ImageListener listener;
        listener.context = this;
        listener.onImageAvailable = imageCallback;

        AImageReader_setImageListener(reader, &listener);

        return reader;
    }
```

Create surface

```
ANativeWindow* createSurface(AImageReader* reader)
{
    ANativeWindow *nativeWindow;
    AImageReader_getWindow(reader, &nativeWindow);

    return nativeWindow;
}
```

The call back of the AImageReader

```
static void process_depth_16(void* context, AImage *image)
{
    uint16_t *data = nullptr;
    int len = 0;
    auto const status = AImage_getPlaneData(image, 0, reinterpret_cast<uint8_t**>(&data), &len);
    if(status != AMEDIA_OK){
        qInfo()<<__func__<<": AImage_getPlaneData fail, error code = "<<status;
        return;
    }
    qInfo()<<__func__<<": image len = "<<len;

    auto *impl = static_cast<pimpl*>(context);
    convert_depth_16_to_cvmat(data, impl->width_, impl->height_);
}

static void imageCallback(void* context, AImageReader* reader)
{
    qDebug()<<__func__;
    int status = -1;
    auto image = get_next_image(reader, &status);
    if(status != AMEDIA_OK){
        qInfo()<<__func__<<": cannot acquire next image, error code = "<<status;
        return;
    }

    int32_t format = -1;
    AImage_getFormat(image.get(), &format);
    if(format == AIMAGE_FORMAT_DEPTH16){
        process_depth_16(context, image.get());
    }else{
        qInfo()<<__func__<<": do not support format = "<<format;
    }
}
```

Copy depth map(this function cause the app crash)

```
cv::Mat convert_depth_16_to_cvmat(uint16_t *data, int32_t width, int32_t height)
{
    auto *depth_ptr = data;
    cv::Mat output(height, width, CV_16U);
    for(int32_t row = 0; row != height; ++row){
        depth_ptr += width * row;
        auto *output_ptr = output.ptr<ushort>(row);
        qInfo()<<__func__<<": row = "<<row; //crash when row equal to 27,sometimes over 50 
        for(int32_t col = 0; col != width; ++col){
            output_ptr[col] = depth_ptr[col];
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Minimum width and height I obtain from the ACAMERA_DEPTH_AVAILABLE_DEPTH_STREAM_CONFIGURATIONS are 480x360. Anything wrong with the codes?

Other utility functions put at [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/vnyWfkgz).

Edit: The length of the data is 345600, that means there should have 172800(480x360) pixels with data types uint16_t

Answer (score 0):

I find out the answer, mate30 do not support depth map, but the native api do not tell us that, maybe the functions of the native api related to depth map not that mature yet.